# Button positioning different on iOS then Windows and Android

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a `span` what has 2 elements, `input` and `svg`.
I want the `svg` to be centered vertically in the `input` field.

I have 3 devices where I'm testing the design of my PWA.

- Windows 10 - Google Chrome
- Android 6.0 - Google Chrome
- iOS 12.+ - Safari

On both Windows and Android it's centered vertically, only not on the iOS device.

Does anyone have an idea what this would fix?

React Component:

```
<StyledInputSpan>
  <StyledInput />
  <StyledClearButton />
</StyledInputSpan>
```

Styled Component:

```
export const StyledInput = styled.input`
  //Reset box-shadow
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;

  display: block;
  padding: 0.75em 2em 0.75em 0.75em; //Extra padding on the right for the clear button.
  font-size: 1em;

  //Hide the standard clear button.
  &[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    display: none;
  }
`;

export const StyledClearButton = styled.button`
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(2.8em - env(safe-area-inset-top)); //env() is for the nodge on iOS.
  right: 0;
`;

const StyledInputSpan = styled.span`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out that using `env(safe-area-inset-top)` is not what I was looking for.

> env(safe-area-inset-top) works only for the top of your app on iOS.
>   When you use `env(safe-area-inset-top)` it push down your app with the height of the `nodge`.

I changed my css/styled component to:

```
export const StyledInput = styled.input`
  //Reset box-shadow
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;

  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.75em 2em 0.75em 0.75em; //Extra padding on the right for the clear button.
  font-size: 1em;

  //Hide the standard clear button.
  &[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    display: none;
  }
`;

export const StyledClearButton = styled.button`
  position: absolute;
  top: 27.5%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  right: 0;
`;

const StyledInputSpan = styled.span`
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`;
```